# How to convert Reactor Flux<Object> to Mono<Void>

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I defined a data provider help class to populate my local DB during testing and I'm using a ReactorCrudRepository. Te defined saveAll method is:

```
<S extends T> Flux<S> saveAll(Publisher<S> entityStream);
```

And my PostgresDataProvider.insertData is returning a Mono because I'm not interested in receive the inserted entities. How can pipeline my current method from Flux to cast into Mono?

```
public Mono<Void> insertData(Flux<Entity> entities) {
    return repository.saveAll(entities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the operator

> then() → will just replay the source terminal signal, resulting in a Mono to indicate that this never signals any onNext.

That allow me to produce a Mono on the onComplete flux's signal.

```
 public Mono<Void> insertData(Flux<RateEntity> rateEntities) {
    return repository.saveAll(rateEntities).then();
  }
```